# Croatian locale for Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

I have been searching for a decent Croatian locale for magento 1.9 but so far nothing. Could you recommend something?

Answer (score 0):

You can [find here](https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales/tree/master/app/locale) a lost of all locale packages.
They are from 2 years ago and they were all downloaded from the magento commerce website when it worked.
I know they are old, but at least it's a place to start.
In addition to that, you can use [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/MagentoTranslationTool) that will help you isolate the texts that require translation on module bases.